# Which unix tools, C libraries, .. have some support for unicode NFC and NFD formats

Tags: unix, unicode

I'm learning about combining characters in Unicode, about the NFC and NFD formats, and this is still new to me.

Are these concepts already supported in some standard Unix tools or libraries? I just searched through the manual for GNU grep and GNU diff and did not find any mention of comparing or searching "modulo NFC", only a caveat that the behaviour of grep -i is not specified for strange characters/locales.

Does there exist versions of `diff` that will let me compare files without triggering a difference between "\x65\xCC\x81" (utf8 for "latin .. e" followed by "combining acute accent") and "\xC3\xA9" (utf8 for "latin .. e with acute")?

And what about versions of `grep` that will let me search for lines containing 'é' without having to worry about its encoding in my files (and in my grep command)?

If the answer is negative, is this just a temporary situation?

[I have the same questions with other basic Unix utilities but grep and diff come first to mind.]

Comment: In a word, no. In two words, write it.

Comment: I mean, there are libraries such as ICU, but no standard tools like grep or diff use anything like it. You can always use [a filter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90100/convert-between-unicode-normalization-forms-on-the-unix-command-line).